# How to pass docx file from Controller into View using AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, docx

**Hi Stack Overflow community, first post, work your magic!**

The problem I'm having is that I can generate my `docx` file, but when I try to return it the data is coming back in a format that I've never seen before? Does anyone know what this is?

[Screenshot of unidentifiable code - it looks like Wingdings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOyty.jpg)

**Starting with the razor view**

```
 //Start action
$('#returnDeductionSheets').click(function () {

    //Retrieve date options for user to select
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ReturnDeductionsSheetList',
        success: function (data) {

            if (data != null) {
                var options = data;

                //Format JSON dates into read-able date time format
                function formatDate(options) {
                    var dateString = options.substring(6);
                    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = currentTime.getDate();
                    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    return date;
                };

                //Check if I have more than one date, then return the options via a Bootbox view
                if (options.length > 1) {
                    bootbox.prompt({
                        title: "Select the Deductions Sheet you would like to print.",
                        inputType: 'checkbox',
                        inputOptions: [
                            {
                                text: 'Deductions commenced on ' + formatDate(options[3]),
                                value: options[2],
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Deductions commenced on ' + formatDate(options[1]),
                                value: options[0],
                            }
                        ],
                        callback: function (result) {
                            //Pass the selected option into another AJAX method to generate the document else return to the view
                            if (result != null) {

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '@Url.Action("DeductionsSheet", "Home")?result=' + result,
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        if (data.fileName != "") {
                                            //window.location = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Download" })/?file=" + data.fileName;
                                            window.location = '/Home/ContractSpecificDocuments?file=' + data.fileName;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                return;
                            };
                        }
                    });

                }
                else {
```

I'm happy that the Bootbox code works and the value that is passed into the `DeductionsSheet ActionResult` in the controller so I will jump to this code.

**DeductionsSheet method (top of the method)** 
The value comes into the method as an array which I get through the [0] index.

```
public ActionResult DeductionsSheet(List<object> result)
{
    //BOILER PLATE CODE
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    XceedDeploymentLicense.SetLicense();

    var dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");

    _replacePatterns = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    int contractNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["ContractNumber"].Value);
    int contractContibutionHistoryId = Convert.ToInt32(result[0]);
```

*The document is generated* 
**DeductionsSheet method (bottom of the method)**

```
document.SaveAs(DocumentOutputDirectory + @"\RMContributions_" + dateStamp + @".docx");
}

string fileName = "RMContributions_" + dateStamp + @".docx";
return File(new FileStream(DocumentOutputDirectory + @"\RMContributions_" + dateStamp + @".docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", fileName);
```

The ActionResult finishes and returns back to the AJAX method, shown below here (same code as in Razor View block above).

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.fileName != "") {
        //window.location = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Download" })/?file=" + data.fileName;
        window.location = '/Home/ContractSpecificDocuments?file=' + data.fileName;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a data-type parse problem, or if something needs serializing, I'm open to all suggestions.

Now I'm not committed to this approach so if anyone can suggest an alternative as long as it works I'm happy. Ideally I would call the AJAX method and pass the data into the controller and then not return to the AJAX method, but I've not found a way of doing this.

I did try a simpler alternative whereby in the Bootbox callback I trigger the DeductionsSheet ActionResult using a jQuery trigger event but with this approach I couldn't get the data to pass into the controller.

**Alternative approach using trigger event**

```
callback: function (result) {
    //Pass the selected option into another AJAX method to generate the document else return to the view
    if (result != null) {

        $('#deductionsSheet').trigger('click', [result]);

    } else {
        return;
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you trying to return Word document back to client-side? if so, your server-sides returns a blob, which you need to convert using  var blobtype = { type: ''<blob type for word docs' }; then, var blob = new Blob([response.data], blobtype);
                                    var windowurl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);var w = window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: are you *sure* this is your first post?